# user time changes for multi thread C program

Tags: c, multithreading, time, openmp

I am experimenting on threads using openMp. My program is about multiplying 2 matrices. The matrices are of constant size, and nothing changes in the program (except the threading part)
I executed the program 3 times using the time command and here are the results:

```
real    0m0.037s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.015s

real    0m0.036s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.015s

real    0m0.035s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.030s
```

Now, I know why the real time changes (even though in this example is more or less the same) but why the user and sys time change that much? 
Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
const int m=150 , n=100 , p=150;
int i , j , k, s;
const int number= 4;
int A[m][p],B[p][n], C[m][n]; //2 , 2

for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < p; j++)
        A[i][j]=number ;

 for(i = 0; i < p; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        B[i][j]= number;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) private(i,j,k)
    for( j = 0; j < n; j++)
        for( i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for( k = 0; k < p; k++)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest deleting `srand(time(NULL));` to get the same numbers to reduce variation in the comparison.

Comment: i dont use the rand function. So i dont think that has anything to do with my problem

Comment: Anyway, i deleted it, but the situation is the same

Comment: The times are so tiny that the differences between them are mostly meaningless.

Comment: What's the 'private' `s`?  A hangover from a bigger version of the code?

Comment: Yes, but that does not influence on the result, does it?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on time for millisecond accuracy. Your program may very well be dominated by thread initialization, which is highly variable . Try increasing the size of the matrix for more stable results.

Comment: This method of doing matrix multiplication is like doing the bubble sort. At the very least you could swap the two innermost loops.